# How to trigger a new pipeline job only on completion of current job using groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Using groovy script how can another pipeline job be triggered as soon as the build completes.
Suppose there are two pipeline A and B, and as soon as pipeline A completes successfully it has to pass its parameters to B and B has to start running. (B has to run only after A terminates)

I tried to trigger the build using the below code, this triggers the job B but job A remains running util the complete execution of job B

```
stage('Artifactory_Publish_Job') {
        try {
    def job = build job: 'Jfrog_Artifactory_Publish', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'buildDateString', value: 'default'], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'WORKSPACE_DIR', value: 'default'], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'Artifactory_Directory', value: 'default']]
        } catch (any) {

            throw any
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the second Job in the Post Step, which is executed once the Job is completed. Additionally you can add following options to the build command `propagate: false, wait: false`

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        success { 
            echo 'Will run only when successful.'
            build job: 'Jfrog_Artifactory_Publish', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'buildDateString', value: 'default'], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'WORKSPACE_DIR', value: 'default'], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'Artifactory_Directory', value: 'default']],  propagate: false, wait: false 
        }
    }
}
```